# How to add setTimeout function to loader in vuejs? (Check Example for better understanding)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, loader

I'm using Element-ui framework table data and I want to add a timer on loader which I don't know how to do it as I'm new to Vuejs.

The loader is currently set as true in a state and it's keep loading but I want to add timer function to load table data but I don't know how to add a timer function in the method.

I've attached the code below for better understanding,

You can also check live example in Codepen by [clicking here](https://codepen.io/umer-zaman/pen/PoZdmbz)

I would really appreciate it if anybody could help me with it, Thanks!

```
<template>
 <el-table
  v-loading="loading"
  :data="tableData"
  style="width: 100%">
  <el-table-column
    prop="date"
    label="Date"
    width="180">
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column
    prop="name"
    label="Name"
    width="180">
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column
    prop="address"
    label="Address">
  </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

```
<script>
  export default {
   data() {
    return {
     tableData: [{
      date: '2016-05-02',
      name: 'John Smith',
      address: 'No.1518,  Jinshajiang Road, Putuo District'
    }, {
      date: '2016-05-04',
      name: 'John Smith',
      address: 'No.1518,  Jinshajiang Road, Putuo District'
    }, {
      date: '2016-05-01',
      name: 'John Smith',
      address: 'No.1518,  Jinshajiang Road, Putuo District'
    }],
    loading: true
   };
  }
 };
</script>
```

Comment: Your example is empty.

Comment: @GabrielWillemann You can open it again and It'll work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a simple time, you must to use a `setTimeout` function. Try something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ loading }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    loading: true,
  }),
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => (this.loading = false), 2000);
  },
};
</script>
```

For more information, you can see the documentation in [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals)